# Run R.NET in and Azure Function

Tags: r, azure, azure-functions, r.net

I am trying to integrate R into an Azure Function.

Instead of just calling the R exe - I want to be able to try the R.NET library to make it easier to pass and collect data between .NET and R. For example, respond to an event.

It runs fine locally, but once deployed as an Azure function, I get various errors.  The latest ": This engine is not running. You may have forgotten to call Initialize"

For anyone else wanting to try this, I had to force the Azure function to run as 64bit, and also install the R extension library to the function. at RDotNet.REngine.CheckEngineIsRunning()

Has anyone had any success?  Is anyone with R.NET experience wanting to help getting to work as an Azure function environment?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet/blob/f3f667db2f8d56d089c7400298367750a03b3413/R.NET/REngine.cs) in R.NET for the functions RDotNet.REngine.GetInstance(), RDotNet.REngine.CheckEngineIsRunning(), and RDotNet.REngine.Initialize(), it appears as though creating the engine instance via RDotNet.REngine.GetInstance() should help you avoid this issue, as after calling that the method should be running, and you should not be encountering this area.

It is possible that you are encountering some error in creating this instance. Looking at the code comments about usage in the above link, it looks like an environment variable needs to be set for `PATH`. It is possible that the code you used to set this up does not work in Azure Functions. You can manually set environment variables in Azure Functions by using [App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings).

Comment: Hi - thanks for the effort - I have tried passing in the PATH and HOME into the initialise instead of the default null.  You are right though - the code may still require some environment settings.